# Class 'ConsoleTVs\Charts\Facades\Charts' not found in laravel Charts

Tags: laravel, charts, highcharts

i'm trying to render a chart with data in database using laravel.
but i'm getting this error

```
    **Class 'ConsoleTVs\Charts\Facades\Charts' not found**
```

but i already add requried providers to app.php,

```
    ConsoleTVs\Charts\ChartsServiceProvider::class,
    'Charts' => ConsoleTVs\Charts\Facades\Charts::class
```

here is my controller,

```
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function admin()
    {

        $suppliers = SupplierData::all();
        $repcounter= SalesRep::count();
        $totalsales= SalesData::count();
        $totalrevenue=SalesData::sum('total_price');

        $chartdata = SalesData::selectRaw('COUNT(*) as count, YEAR(dateOfSale) year, MONTH(dateofSale) month')
            ->groupBy('year', 'month')
            ->get();
        $chart=Charts::database($chartdata,'bar','highcharts')
            ->title("Sales Details")
            ->elementLabel("Total Sales")
            ->dimensions(1000,500)
            ->responsive(false);

        return view('dashboard', compact('suppliers','repcounter','totalsales','totalrevenue','chart'));
```

and here is my html part,

```
 <div>
   {!! $chart->render() !!}
                    </div>
```

so can anyone help with this?

I follow this video tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yAGVB4ZIQ4o

Comment: What is your laravel version ?

Comment: it is Laravel 5.7.12

Comment: Then you don;t have to register the service provider, according to their doc, right ?

Comment: yeah. i tried without it too. it didn't change the error though :(

Comment: The package doesn;t provide a Facade. check https://charts.erik.cat/create_charts.html#create-a-chart-class to how charts are created.

Comment: then what should i do?

Comment: Follow the link. BTW, Why do you have `Charts::database(` .. in your code ? It's not even in the doc.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yAGVB4ZIQ4o i followed this link's steps. i'm new to this chart creating thing. don't have a clear idea

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The package, [**ConsoleTVs/Charts v6**](https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts), doesn't provide a Facade approach.

Please check [**charts.erik.cat/create_charts.html#create-a-chart-class**](http://charts.erik.cat/create_charts.html#create-a-chart-class) to start creating charts using the **ConsoleTVs/Charts v6**

The video tutorial you are following is using **ConsoleTVs/Charts v5**. It does support Facade approach.

If you want to continue with the video, You need to downgrade the package.

Remove v6

```
composer remove consoletvs/charts
```

And install v5

```
composer require "consoletvs/charts:5.*"
```

Since you are using latest version of the Laravel, I highly recommend to use the latest version of **consoletvs/charts**.

Comment: very useful - worked like a charm with my environment - php7.4 and laravel 5

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work for me, remove the V6 using the command and install v5 , still, errors generated 

  

- Root composer.json requires consoletvs/charts 5.*, found consoletvs/charts[dev-main, 6.5.6] but it does not match the constraint.
    -

Comment: Installing v5, gives this error "Could not find package consoletvs/charts in a version matching 5.* ". I think version 5 is no longer on the market